# undefined Unable to resolve module react-native-fs

Tags: android, react-native

```
ERROR  [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module react-native-fs from C:\Users\20020\Documents\GitHub\pmt-mobile\src\screens\Project\index.js: react-native-fs could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  11 | import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
  12 | import RNFileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';
> 13 | import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
     |                   ^
  14 | import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown';
  15 | import { projectApiCall } from '../../apiService/apiService';
  16 | import { TabScreenHeader, ProjectCard, EmptyListComponent } from '../../components';]
```

I want to import react native fs in my project.

Answer (score 1):

- the react-native-fs module is not installed in your project. To resolve this issue, you need to install the react-native-fs module using either npm or yarn.

  ```
  npm install react-native-fs

  yarn add react-native-fs
  ```
- The error you'regetting is because of the react-native-fs module is not properly linked to your project. This is a common issue when using modules that require linking.

  ```
  react-native link react-native-fs
  ```

Comment: I am getting that error after the installation

Comment: @Somesh K i update my answer can you check & try to get a solution.